# Python slice with del statement

Tags: python, slice, del

Why does this:

```
del a[:]
```

delete all entries in the list `a`?

As far as I understand, `a[:]` returns a copy of `a`. So shouldn't `del a[:]` delete the copy of `a`?

Comment: Because that's what it's defined to do? `del` is a statement, not a function, so it's not like you're passing a slice to it.

Comment: `a[:]` doesn't return a copy it returns a slice, for example `a[:] = [1,2]` replaces the contents of `a` not a copy of `a`. Similarly `del` on a slice is defined as deleting the elements of that slice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`del`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) is a special statement that will check the original value and delete it using the given slice.
It calls [`__delitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) on the object and the object itself handles the deletion.

If you're curious regarding the operation happening under the hood, you're welcome to implement the following class and use the `del` statement with different slices or key references:

```
class A:
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        print(key)
```

The test in the interpreter:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> del a[:]
slice(None, None, None)
>>> del a[2]
2
>>> del a["test"]
test
```

Comment: So if I do `del a[:]` it calls `a.__delitem__(i)` for every `i`  within the slice, but if I do `del a` it just deletes the object `a` itself?

Comment: @spiderface It hands over `slice(None, None, None)` to `a.__delitem__` if you use `a[:]` but if you do `del a` it indeed deletes the object (by removing the reference and if no other reference exists it calls the object's `__del__` and deletes it)

Comment: @spiderface: Not exactly. If you `del a`, then that reference to the `list` goes away, but if it is referenced elsewhere, those references are unchanged. `del a[:]` releases the references to the _contents_ of `a`, so both `a` and any other reference to that `list` now see an empty `list`.

Comment: @Bharel: It only calls the `__del__` if the last reference was released; it's important to distinguish releasing references (can happen many times) from actually deleting the object (happens once, when the final reference is released).

Comment: @ShadowRanger edited the comment at the same time of your post ;-)